# grok filter to select specific words from message field

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

```
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Data\data.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"

  }
}
filter {
    if [type] == "apache" {
        grok {
                    match => ["message", "%{COMBINEDAPACHELOG} "]
        }
    }mutate{
           remove_field => ["@timestamp"]
           remove_field => ["host"]
           remove_field => ["@version"]
           remove_field => ["path"]
    }   
}

output {
    elasticsearch{
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "logdata2"
    document_type => "logs"
    }
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

Here comes the problem I´ve run into:

I want to just pick out some words but have never been able to get it right.

What I wanted was just to get a string with timestamp that lies inside the message string. along with an other word, say OrderCreated.

Is it possible to go this way to select specific string/word from message field?

dissect worked just fine but now i´ve run in to a problem i didn´t had earlier.

```
dissect filter 
input {
  file {
    path => "C:\Data\Logs\testrunning.log"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "NUL"

  }
}
  filter {
    dissect {
      mapping => {
        "message" => "%{ts} %{+ts} %{+ts} %{src} %{} : %{msg}"
      }
    }mutate { remove_field => "@timestamp" 
    remove_field => "pid"
    remove_field => "prog"
    remove_field => "@version"
    remove_field => "host"
    remove_field => "path"
    remove_field => "src"
  } 
}
output {
    elasticsearch{
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "logdata12"
    document_type => "logs"
    }
    stdout {codec => rubydebug}
}
```

The output is following. this is new to me, the "\r" part that wasnt there before.. is this familiar for anyone? how do i fix this part?

```
{
    "message" => "General 2018-05-17 15:47:33.149 : StatusInformationSomeData.Unsubscribe() \r",
        "msg" => "StatusInformationSomeData.Unsubscribe() \r",
         "ts" => "General 2018-05-17 15:47:33.149"
}
{
    "message" => "\r",
        "msg" => "\r",
         "ts" => "  "
}
```

Comment: Daniel, perhaps you should try with `dissect {}` filter, is more friendly than grok and also faster. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-dissect.html

Comment: thanks alot, íve just got started with it, and its looking way more promising than grok!

Comment: would you be able to show us an actual log ?

Comment: @SufiyanGhori, problem is solved, the reason  as i understod was that the lengt of the message in log cased it some how to automaticli split when dissected. I might be wrong. but anyway, the problem is not there anymore, and i went back and changed to shape of logs to much more cleaner and easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dissect{}`. As an example, if you have a log line such as:

`198.41.30.203 - - [21/May/2018:14:36:35 -0500] "GET /tag/eclipse/feed/ HTTP/1.1" 404 5232 "-" "UniversalFeedParser/4.2-pre-308-svn +http://feedparser.org/"`

Your dissect could be something like this, and you can even convert datatypes. The performance of dissect is much better than grok:

```
dissect {
    mapping => {
        "message" => '%{source_ip} %{} %{username} [%{raw_timestamp}] "%{http_verb} %{http_path} %{http_version}" %{http_response} %{http_bytes} "%{site}" "%{useragent}"'
        convert_datatype => {
            http_bytes => "int"
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: dissect was a bit more efficent than grok, part of the problem was now solved, thanks alot!